# PHP fopen and fwrite throws no error, but the files aren't written to or created. Why?

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite

I am simply trying to pass some information to a PHP script using jquery $.post() and then write that information to a text file.  The post is working just fine.  No errors are thrown, as far as I know...but the files aren't created and when I put the file there it isn't written to.  Am I missing something?  Here's my code.

JavaScript

```
  var ajaxData = { IGC: JSON.stringify(containerObj), filename: newFilePath };
  $.post( "../php/generateIGC.php", ajaxData, function(data) {
        $('#generated_textarea').val(data)
  })
```

Originally I tried to interpret what was being sent and write it to the file.

PHP

```
<?php
  $data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['IGC']), true);
  $myFile = $_POST['filename'];
  $handle = fopen($myFile, 'w'); //or die('Cannot open file:  '.$myFile); 
  fwrite($handle,$data);
  fclose($handle);
  echo "File successfully created";
?>
```

Then I gave up and just tried to write to a file that I created for testing, and even this won't work.

```
<?php

  $data = 'dfjlsdkfsdlfkj';
  $handle = fopen('test.txt', 'w'); //or die('Cannot open file:  '.$myFile); 
  fwrite($handle,$data);
  fclose($handle);

 ?>
```

I'm not getting any error in the browser, and the post succeeds.  The only indication I have that something isn't working is the file not being written to or created, and when I access (data) I just get a string of the php script.  What am I doing wrong here?

UPDATE:

I changed the php script to this

```
<?php
 $data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['IGC']), true);
 $myFile = $_POST['filename']
 $handle = fopen('test.txt', 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$myFile); 
 fwrite($handle,$data);
 fclose($handle);
 return $data;
 ?>
```

and now I get the error:

kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 1.)

Here is the post function if it helps

```
    function genCode() {
  var path = $('#path_to_image').val();
  var index = path.length
  for (var i = 1; i<=3; i++) {
    index = path.lastIndexOf('/',index-1)
  }
  var fileToCreate = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/')+1,path.lastIndexOf('.'))+'.igc'
  var newFilePath = path.substring(0,path.lastIndexOf('.'))+'.igc'
  containerObj["target_container"] = $('#target_container').val();
  containerObj["img_path"] = path.substring(index+1);
  containerObj["img_dims"] = {x: w, y: h};
  containerObj["mode"] = $('#number_of_axes').val();
  containerObj["sd"] = {x1: $('#sd_x1').val(), y1: $('#sd_y1').val(), x2: $('#sd_x2').val(), y2: $('#sd_y2').val()};
  containerObj["number_of_graphs"] = $('#number_of_graphs').val();
  var show_waypoints = false;
  containerObj["show_waypoints"] = false;
  //$('#generated_textarea').val("attachGraph.addGraph(" + JSON.stringify(containerObj, null, '\t') + ");");
  var ajaxData = { IGC: JSON.stringify(containerObj), filename: newFilePath };
 /*   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "../php/generateIGC.php",
      data: ajaxData,
      success: function() {
        $('#generated_textarea').val("File created.")
      }
      })
    })
   */ $.post( "../php/generateIGC.php", ajaxData, function(data) {
        $('#generated_textarea').val(data)
    } )
}
```

Comment: You might try adding the `full path` to where the file should be opened/written and see if that resolves it for you.

Comment: Do you have full error reporting enabled?

Comment: For one thing you have a missing closing semi-colon in `$myFile = $_POST['filename']` - plus `$myFile` is just a variable, nothing else is using it/passed to it.

Comment: i would console log `data` in your $.post() just to make sure there's something there.  and again in your PHP i would output `$data` just to make sure it isn't empty. you might try `escape(data)` in your js. there may be characters that are choking your js or even you php i suppose

Comment: Your second PHP code with `dfjlsdkfsdlfkj` inside it, works. Check your file permissions.

Comment: I have tried adding the full path before and it didn't work.  The semi-colon may have been an issue, but it doesn't explain why the second bit of code won't run.  Also, how can I enable full error reporting?

Comment: @ordanj If you run your 2nd bit of code from inside the same place as `test.txt` then you'll see it created. Otherwise, try first creating `test.txt` as a blank file, set the permissions to `777` then try it again. If it writes to it, then you have a permissions issue.

Comment: @ordanj Try my theory without your JavaScript codes, just like it is, a straight PHP call. Now if THAT works, then it's your JS. Process of elimination.

Comment: @ordanj, your current working directory may be protected from writing for www-data user or any apache used user name. You can try to login as root, and changer owner of the directory to www-data user.

Comment: You need to post your form. I can't test without knowing how `$_POST['IGC']` is being passed/used.

Comment: `bool chmod ( string $filename , int $mode )` Would this be how I set permissions?

Comment: `chmod("test.txt", 0777);` put that under `$handle = fopen('test.txt', 'w')`

Comment: Thanks.  I just don't understand why the .post works, but none of the echo functions do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally "solved" this problem.  I had been accidentally running the html page locally, and not through the apache server, so the php couldn't run.  Additionally, the txt files didn't have write access and there were some errors in my code originally.  All pretty silly though.

Answer (score 3):

It can me a lot of things, you should be aware of the path you are trying to write and also you should tweak the configuration of PHP to show errors since all file operations produce a WARNING that does not halt your script.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1); // show errors
error_reporting(-1); // of all levels
date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); // PHP will complain about on this error level

if (!isset($_POST['IGC'])) { // Test if this was posted
    echo "IGC not defined";
    exit;
}

if (!isset($_POST['filename'])) { // Test if this was posted too
    echo "filename not defined."
    exit;
}
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['IGC']), true);
$myFile = $_POST['filename'];
$fileToWrite = 'test.txt';
if (!is_writable($fileToWrite)) { // Test if the file is writable
    echo "Cannot write to {$fileToWrite}";
    exit;
}

$handle = fopen($fileToWrite, 'w');
if (!is_resource($handle)) { // Test if PHP could open the file
    echo "Could not open {$fileToWrite} for writting."
    exit;
}

fwrite($handle,$data);
fclose($handle);
echo "File successfully created";
?>
```

This script as your upload PHP script should give you better details on your problem. The only thing you would have to be sure is where the file you are editing is, and if PHP has permission to write to it.

If you do not use an absolute path on the filename, PHP will try to write in the directory of the script.

Comment: I gave this a shot.  Like before, the file isn't created and `$('#generated_textarea').val(data)` just writes the entire script to `#generated_textarea` No errors thrown.

Comment: I feel like at the very least, echo should be sending back proper data.  Am I not accessing it properly?

Comment: What is the content on the textarea? You are probably not accessing the PHP properly as you said, there is anything on the log at the web server (access, error...)?

Comment: Well, I actually think the problem might be that php isn't enabled.  I removed the comment from #LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so but must have missed another step.

Comment: After removing the comment you must restart Apache. Make sure PHP is installed running `php -v` on a shell and by creating and opening a page containing `<?php phpinfo();`.

Comment: PHP 5.3.26 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jul  7 2013 18:22:47) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies

Comment: So php is definitely running, and I restarted apache.  Is there any special way to open a php file that I don't understand?  I've been trying to open it through the browser but haven't had any success.

Comment: when I run from the command line I get 'Could not open input file: test.php'